# Google Apps Script messing up JSON values

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´m using a Google Apps Script, trying to import Bitcoin-exchange rate information to a Google Spreadsheet. I use this code:

```
var url = "https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var lcharts_data = JSON.parse(json)

function bitcoin(){
  var b = lcharts_data["ticker"]["avg"];
  return b;
}
```

The JSON-file looks like this:

```
{"ticker":
  {"high":947.99902,
   "low":817.64001,
   "avg":882.819515,
   "vol":24625847.06001,
   "vol_cur":28189.09956,
   "last":930,
   "buy":930,
   "sell":929.998,
   "updated":1385575341,
   "server_time":1385575342}
  }
}
```

Yet b returns as 22.49. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works as expected. Do use `JSON.parse()` and not the `Utilities.jsonParse()` as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I can't see on [Googles Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#jsonParse(String)) that the latter is deprecated?

Comment: @vletech See 18 November: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#november_2013

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Thanks for the link, they should add that to the main documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

I use the similar method for receiving the data but I parse it slightly different. For example:

```
var url = "https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.toString();
var lcharts_data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Notice the `toString()` method and the native `Utilities.jsonParse()` method. I tried `JSON.parse()` but that didn't work for me.

Also are using an API key to access the data? Have tried above but it's timing out.

Comment: @user3042831 The methods I have mentioned above works for a different API service I am using, but I can't test your bit coin one as I don't get a response.

Comment: As @JacobJanTuinstra pointed out `Utilities.jsonParse()` is deprecated  (but still working for the moment) but the outcome from changing to `JSON.parse()` doesn't differ.

Answer (score 0):

As at when I tested your url, the JSON response returned was:

```
{  
"ticker":{  
    "high":421.70001,
    "low":418,
    "avg":419.850005,
    "vol":2361935.91952,
    "vol_cur":5620.41595,
    "last":420.168,
    "buy":420.168,
    "sell":419.853,
    "updated":1460626271,
    "server_time":1460626273
     }
}
```

Here's the code that returns the value for 'avg':

```
var url = "https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var lcharts_data = JSON.parse(json);

function bitcoin(){
  var b = lcharts_data.ticker.avg;
  return b;
}
```